# Sql select last record with specific WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `login`:

```
ID - DATE - USER_ID
1 - 13.4.2016 20:00 - 1
2 - 13.4.2016 20:10 - 1
3 - 13.4.2016 20:20 - 1
4 - 13.4.2016 20:30 - 1
5 - 13.4.2016 21:00 - 2
```

How to select last row of `user_id` (last user login  `:-)` )?

**Output:** `4 - 13.4.2016 20:30 - 1`

My try not working:

```
SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY ID DESC WHERE USER_ID = 1
```

But I get sql syntax error, I don't know why, can you help me please?

Thank you for your replye.

Comment: `select .. from .. where .. order by .. limit 1` is the correct order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORDER BY` the date field `DESCENDING` and keep only the first row returned with `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT *
FROM login
WHERE user_id=1
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You get a syntax error in your query because your `WHERE` clause comes after your `ORDER` clause

Comment: Would be nice if you also write, why OP gets a syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

Try the query below:

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM login order by date desc

output: 4 - 13.4.2016 20:30 - 1

Comment: this is for  **MySQL** so your `TOP 1` is wrong and you are missing the `WHERE` clause.